# Need a way to increment/decrement counter of files in a dir in Firebase Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have an app that uploads files into a folder in my main firebase storage bucket.

It goes like `/records/{files_here}`

1. Basically, I send a file to that path
2. Firebase Cloud Functions will detect that there is a change (if the change is a .onFinalize or .onDelete type) then will update a document field from my Firestore.

This works perfectly when sending 1 file at a time. If I send more than 2 files at a time, the counters start to overlap?
for example, uploading 3 files but the counter went up from 0 to 4.

This is how I have set up my functions to increase/decrease counter.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

// detects new files on dir records/
exports.uploadedRecordsStorageCreateCounter = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {
    let matchDir = "records";
    let dir = object.name.substring(0, object.name.lastIndexOf("/"));
    if (dir == matchDir) {
      await db
        .collection("counters")
        .doc("records")
        .update({ count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
    }
    return;
  });

// detects deletes on dir records/
exports.uploadedRecordsStorageDeleteCounter = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onDelete(async (object) => {
    let matchDir = "records";
    let dir = object.name.substring(0, object.name.lastIndexOf("/"));
    if (dir == matchDir) {
      await db
        .collection("counters")
        .doc("records")
        .update({ count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) });
    }
    return;
  });
```

Is there a better way of implementing a counter?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps use a [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) or update the counter atomically in a transaction

Comment: it doesn't seem very efficient to me. It doesn't even explain what shards are, It seems to also charge a lot depending on the number of documents. I think I'll just do a  periodic check on the storage to grab the amount.

Comment: Please edit the question to add and show the logging that illustrates what you mean by "the counters go crazy".  There should be a clear description of the behavior you observe that's different than what you expect.  Anyone should be able to duplicate that behavior using the information you provide.

Comment: done, updated the post for clarity

Comment: I believe this happens due to your function getting executed several times which is [expected behavior](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees) for background funtions. You will need to come up with other counter strategy in this case.

Comment: which is why I am asking here? I can't find a way to solve this. Maybe add some kind of transactions that intentionally delay for at least 1 sec? because I think this problem has to do with firebase functions being slow at start. I think it gets faster when it executes at first but is slow to start up.

Comment: This is a feature of background functions and you cannot overcome them it. You can try updating the counter directly from the app that uploads the file. Also consider 1 update/sec limitation of Firestore and [solution](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/counters) to it.